# Errors not recorded in ELMAH

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm using ELMAH in my mvc project to record errors. I realised that sometimes errors not recorded. So I wrapped the statements in try..catch and called `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);` but nothing get recorded again for that specific error. So I tried to step into ELMAH source code (using Reflector VS addin). And I saw this exception in elmah:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Text="<br>").
 StackTrace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
```

Actual source code: `this._form = CopyCollection(request.Form);` in `public Error(System.Exception e, HttpContext context)` in `Error.cs`. and CopyCollection method:

```
private static NameValueCollection CopyCollection(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    if ((collection != null) && (collection.Count != 0))
    {
        return new NameValueCollection(collection);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So .Net does not allow creating new NameValueCollection from *dangerous* form data. I have a lot of Html editors in my application and I want ELMAH to record errors in any situation.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this is due to a breaking change introduced by ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147). A workaround right now would be to ask ASP.NET to revert back to the older behavior by adding the following to your configuration:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

For a more complete discussion, see [issue #217](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=217) on the [ELMAH project site](http://code.google.com/p/elmah).

Comment: I noticed that issue #217 was fixed in Sept. 2012. Are there any plans  to release a new version of Elmah?

Comment: @AtifAziz PLUSONE! Please push to nuget? This was patched ages ago... If the problem is that one needs framework>=4 then maybe there could be a v4 nuget package?